# How can I get access_token lifetime?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, access-token, dribbble-api

Here is API for Dribbble http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/oauth/
During providing OAuth in my Android App I found some problem case: 
How can I get access_token lifetime for calculating expiration date for updating my access token?

Comment: It's based on the API provider and I didn't see anything relevant to expire time in dribble

Comment: endless access_token?

Comment: Do you have an actual example token? At first glance the token in the API example does not look like a JWT token, which you could decode

Comment: Actually, I dont know how JWT token looks like:/
Debug mode shows me "6cdb170a47d783b8a95cbad4dcbddbed8c952ec88dd5ad9a8ed6771870***".
 So, what do You think? Is it endless token or I can get token lifetime in some way?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an access token, the authorization server may return information about the lifetime of the access token using the **`expires_in`** response parameter. You can find the definition of the parameter in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework). However, because `expires_in` is an **optional** parameter, the authorization server may **not** return the parameter.

If the authorization server provides an API by which you can get information about access tokens (e.g. API that complies with [RFC 7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)), you can get information about access token lifetime. Such an API is called "**introspection API**".

If the authorization server does not return `expires_in` and does not provide any introspection API, you have to give up getting information about access token lifetime.

Comment: What about Dribbble API? I didnt get it.. How can I define is Dribbble API introspection or not?